# Spring JPA to store entity within entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data JPA with hibernate at the back with H2 in memory database.

I have following entities:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long entityAId;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA")
    private List<EntityB> entityBList;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "entityAId")
    private EntityA entityA;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Here are my repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, Long> {

}

@Repository
public interface EntityBRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityB, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "FROM EntityB b where b.entityA.entityAId = ?1")
    public List<EntityB> getEntityBByEntityAId(Long entityAId);
}
```

My question is:

If i have an instance of `entityA` with 'n' instances of `entityB` in it, and if i call `entityARepository.save(entityA);` then will it save entityB as well (is it possible?)? I tried this but it didn't worked for me. I did tried doing

```
entityARepository.save(entityA);
entityBRepository.save(entityBList);
```

Which saved the result. But when i retrieved `entityA` using `findOne` method from repository by an `entityAId`, i get an empty list without any instance of `EntityB` type.

I even tried querying `entityBRepository` separately by `entityAId`, but i get an empty `entityB` result list.

Can somebody please help me to know what exactly am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the Cascade-Configuration.

Please try

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

Save it by using:

```
entityARepository.save(entityA);
```

For more information about Cascade-Types have a look at this [JPA and Hibernate Cascade Types](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

**Edit:**
There also can be some config errors... is your test transactional? Here a TestNG Snippet:

```
@Test
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-test-config.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class MyRepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

Is your spring-config ok? Does it contain something like this?

```
    <!-- only components from this package can be wired by spring --> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.*" />

    <!-- Directory to scan for repository classes -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.domain.repository" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>com.xxx.domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Comment: This should work, something else must be wrong in your config. How did you inject your entityARepository? How did you test it? Can you show us your spring config?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check the spring- and test-config.

Comment: No I am not using any spring configuration. I am using Spring 4 with `@Repository` annotation. Look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) for details.

Comment: I'am using Spring 4.1.6 and CrudRepository but without the configuration in my answer it does not work (or at least i don't know how to get it runnable without it). And your link also includes spring-config, for example see 1.3 point 3. You will find this part of the configuration also in the config i posted you in my answer...

Comment: And if you have no spring-config, how do you wire your repository into your test/service?

Comment: In my service, i autowire the repositories. So to unit test it, i just mock it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105028/discussion-between-user3227576-and-sma).